# Tomcat crashes unexpectedly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat

In my java application tomcat shutdown unexpectedly.It only shows to the website that, 'The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems.

> Please try again later.
>   'Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8l DAV/2 mod_jk/1.2.31 Server at example.com Port 8080'

Also i have checked the catalina log and nothing much i found out. I am checking the err_pid file for jvm error, which says there was an error, but i cannot figure it out, i am not a server architect.

server details:

> os: Red Hat Linux
>   jdk: 1.5.0_03
>   tomcat: 5.5.9
>   ram: 16 gb
>   Here is the err_pid.log file. I think you will be able to find out the issue.
>
> ### err_pid.log

```
# An unexpected error has been detected by HotSpot Virtual Machine:
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00bfa6f6, pid=28643, tid=1309596576
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (1.5.0_03-b07 mixed mode)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0x276f6]  _setjmp+0x6
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x4feb6748):  JavaThread "TP-Processor21" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=28707]

siginfo:si_signo=11, si_errno=0, si_code=1, si_addr=0x00000010

Registers:
EAX=0x00000000, EBX=0x4dde35a8, ECX=0x08a1f558, EDX=0x00000010
ESP=0x4e0ec1b4, EBP=0x4e0ec270, ESI=0x5338a7e8, EDI=0x4feb6748
EIP=0x00bfa6f6, CR2=0x00000010, EFLAGS=0x00010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x4e0ec1b4)
0x4e0ec1b4:   4dd8726e 00000010 4e0ec29c 00000001
0x4e0ec1c4:   080e6a38 4e0ec2a8 4e0ec238 4feb7298
0x4e0ec1d4:   080e6a24 4e0ec1f8 00000029 00000000
0x4e0ec1e4:   51335398 51c00068 00010000 00000001
0x4e0ec1f4:   00000001 51c00048 4e0ec278 4feb7298
0x4e0ec204:   00d00840 00000030 4e0ec278 00cf3f03
0x4e0ec214:   00cf3eb1 00000001 51c00048 00000000
0x4e0ec224:   4dd8fdf1 00000000 00cf5ab4 00000170 

Instructions: (pc=0x00bfa6f6)
0x00bfa6e6:   d1 59 5a c3 90 90 90 90 90 90 31 c0 8b 54 24 04
0x00bfa6f6:   89 5a 00 89 72 04 89 7a 08 8d 4c 24 04 89 4a 10 

Stack: [0x4e06d000,0x4e0ee000),  sp=0x4e0ec1b4,  free space=508k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libc.so.6+0x276f6]  _setjmp+0x6
C  [libfontmanager.so+0x45d4d]
C  [libfontmanager.so+0x46349]  Java_sun_font_FileFont_getGlyphImage+0xcb
j  sun.font.FileFont.getGlyphImage(JI)J+0
j  sun.font.FileFontStrike.getGlyphImagePtr(I)J+62
j  sun.font.FileFontStrike.getGlyphMetrics(I)Ljava/awt/geom/Point2D$Float;+25
j  sun.font.CompositeStrike.getGlyphMetrics(I)Ljava/awt/geom/Point2D$Float;+11
j  sun.font.StandardGlyphVector$GlyphStrike.addDefaultGlyphAdvance(ILjava/awt/geom/Point2D$Float;)V+5
j  sun.font.StandardGlyphVector.initPositions()V+106
j  sun.font.StandardGlyphVector.getLogicalBounds()Ljava/awt/geom/Rectangle2D;+5
j  org.krysalis.barcode4j.output.java2d.Java2DCanvasProvider.deviceText(Ljava/lang/String;DDDLjava/lang/String;DLorg/krysalis/barcode4j/TextAlignment;)V+39
j  org.krysalis.barcode4j.output.bitmap.BitmapCanvasProvider.deviceText(Ljava/lang/String;DDDLjava/lang/String;DLorg/krysalis/barcode4j/TextAlignment;)V+16
j  org.krysalis.barcode4j.output.Canvas.drawText(Ljava/lang/String;DDDLjava/lang/String;DLorg/krysalis/barcode4j/TextAlignment;)V+16
j  org.krysalis.barcode4j.impl.DrawingUtil.drawText(Lorg/krysalis/barcode4j/output/Canvas;Lorg/krysalis/barcode4j/impl/AbstractBarcodeBean;Ljava/lang/String;DDDLorg/krysalis/barcode4j/TextAlignment;)V+29
j  org.krysalis.barcode4j.impl.DefaultCanvasLogicHandler.endBarcode()V+168
j  org.krysalis.barcode4j.impl.code128.Code128LogicImpl.generateBarcodeLogic(Lorg/krysalis/barcode4j/ClassicBarcodeLogicHandler;Ljava/lang/String;)V+92
j  org.krysalis.barcode4j.impl.code128.Code128Bean.generateBarcode(Lorg/krysalis/barcode4j/output/CanvasProvider;Ljava/lang/String;)V+51
j  repaircenter.common.BarCode.render(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+130
j  com.ge.appl.tsf.shells.web.TSFWebPresentationManager.callTSFPO(Lcom/ge/appl/tsf/shells/common/TSFParams;Ljava/lang/String;)V+46
j  com.ge.appl.tsf.shells.web.TSFWebPresentationManager.render(Lcom/ge/appl/tsf/shells/common/TSFParams;Lcom/ge/appl/tsf/kernel/TSFResponse;)V+202
j  com.ge.appl.tsf.shells.web.TSFDispatcher.service(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+728
j  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+30
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+354
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+101
j  repaircenter.common.listingObjects.SessionFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+157
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+117
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+101
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+607
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+285
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+64
j  org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+6
j  org.apache.catalina.valves.FastCommonAccessLogValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+6

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  sun.font.FileFont.getGlyphImage(JI)J+0
j  sun.font.FileFontStrike.getGlyphImagePtr(I)J+62
j  sun.font.FileFontStrike.getGlyphMetrics(I)Ljava/awt/geom/Point2D$Float;+25
j  sun.font.CompositeStrike.getGlyphMetrics(I)Ljava/awt/geom/Point2D$Float;+11
j  sun.font.StandardGlyphVector$GlyphStrike.addDefaultGlyphAdvance(ILjava/awt/geom/Point2D$Float;)V+5
j  sun.font.StandardGlyphVector.initPositions()V+106
j  sun.font.StandardGlyphVector.getLogicalBounds()Ljava/awt/geom/Rectangle2D;+5
j  org.krysalis.barcode4j.output.java2d.Java2DCanvasProvider.deviceText(Ljava/lang/String;DDDLjava/lang/String;DLorg/krysalis/barcode4j/TextAlignment;)V+39
j  org.krysalis.barcode4j.output.bitmap.BitmapCanvasProvider.deviceText(Ljava/lang/String;DDDLjava/lang/String;DLorg/krysalis/barcode4j/TextAlignment;)V+16
j  org.krysalis.barcode4j.output.Canvas.drawText(Ljava/lang/String;DDDLjava/lang/String;DLorg/krysalis/barcode4j/TextAlignment;)V+16
j  org.krysalis.barcode4j.impl.DrawingUtil.drawText(Lorg/krysalis/barcode4j/output/Canvas;Lorg/krysalis/barcode4j/impl/AbstractBarcodeBean;Ljava/lang/String;DDDLorg/krysalis/barcode4j/TextAlignment;)V+29
j  org.krysalis.barcode4j.impl.DefaultCanvasLogicHandler.endBarcode()V+168
j  org.krysalis.barcode4j.impl.code128.Code128LogicImpl.generateBarcodeLogic(Lorg/krysalis/barcode4j/ClassicBarcodeLogicHandler;Ljava/lang/String;)V+92
j  org.krysalis.barcode4j.impl.code128.Code128Bean.generateBarcode(Lorg/krysalis/barcode4j/output/CanvasProvider;Ljava/lang/String;)V+51
j  repaircenter.common.BarCode.render(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+130
j  com.ge.appl.tsf.shells.web.TSFWebPresentationManager.callTSFPO(Lcom/ge/appl/tsf/shells/common/TSFParams;Ljava/lang/String;)V+46
j  com.ge.appl.tsf.shells.web.TSFWebPresentationManager.render(Lcom/ge/appl/tsf/shells/common/TSFParams;Lcom/ge/appl/tsf/kernel/TSFResponse;)V+202
j  com.ge.appl.tsf.shells.web.TSFDispatcher.service(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+728
j  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+30
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+354
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+101
j  repaircenter.common.listingObjects.SessionFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+157
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+117
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+101
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+607
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+285
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+64
j  org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+6
j  org.apache.catalina.valves.FastCommonAccessLogValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+6
v  ~C2IAdapter
J  org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V
v  ~I2CAdapter
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+42
j  org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(Lorg/apache/coyote/Request;Lorg/apache/coyote/Response;)V+141
j  org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(Lorg/apache/jk/core/Msg;Lorg/apache/jk/core/MsgContext;)I+177
j  org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(Lorg/apache/jk/core/Msg;Lorg/apache/jk/core/MsgContext;)I+330
j  org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(Lorg/apache/jk/core/Msg;Lorg/apache/jk/core/MsgContext;)I+191
j  org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(Lorg/apache/jk/core/MsgContext;)V+101
j  org.apache.jk.common.SocketConnection.runIt([Ljava/lang/Object;)V+8
j  org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run()V+167
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x080bc5e0 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29000]
  0x4fefa568 JavaThread "Thread-54" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28815]
  0x4febabb8 JavaThread "TP-Monitor" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28712]
  0x4feb9e08 JavaThread "TP-Processor25" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=28711]
  0x4feb9058 JavaThread "TP-Processor24" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28710]
  0x4feb82a8 JavaThread "TP-Processor23" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28709]
  0x4feb74f8 JavaThread "TP-Processor22" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28708]
=>0x4feb6748 JavaThread "TP-Processor21" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=28707]
  0x4feb59e8 JavaThread "TP-Processor20" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28706]
  0x50bef758 JavaThread "TP-Processor19" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28705]
  0x50bee9a8 JavaThread "TP-Processor18" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28704]
  0x50bedbf8 JavaThread "TP-Processor17" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28703]
  0x50bece48 JavaThread "TP-Processor16" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28702]
  0x50bec098 JavaThread "TP-Processor15" daemon [_thread_in_Java, id=28701]
  0x50beb348 JavaThread "TP-Processor14" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28700]
  0x50023110 JavaThread "TP-Processor13" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28699]
  0x50022398 JavaThread "TP-Processor12" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28698]
  0x500215e8 JavaThread "TP-Processor11" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28697]
  0x50020838 JavaThread "TP-Processor10" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28696]
  0x5001fa88 JavaThread "TP-Processor9" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28695]
  0x5001ed10 JavaThread "TP-Processor8" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28694]
  0x5001dfd8 JavaThread "TP-Processor7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28693]
  0x50bd7e10 JavaThread "TP-Processor6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28692]
  0x50bd7110 JavaThread "TP-Processor5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28691]
  0x50015be0 JavaThread "TP-Processor4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28690]
  0x50015760 JavaThread "TP-Processor3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28689]
  0x500152e0 JavaThread "TP-Processor2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28688]
  0x50014e60 JavaThread "TP-Processor1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28687]
  0x5073c1e0 JavaThread "http-159.82.103.149-19332-Monitor" [_thread_blocked, id=28686]
  0x5073b430 JavaThread "http-159.82.103.149-19332-Processor25" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=28685]
  0x5073a680 JavaThread "http-159.82.103.149-19332-Processor24" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28684]
  0x507398d0 JavaThread "http-159.82.103.149-19332-Processor23" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28683]
  0x50738b38 JavaThread "http-159.82.103.149-19332-Processor22" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28682]
  0x5096aa88 JavaThread "http-159.82.103.149-19332-Processor21" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28681]
  0x50969cd8 JavaThread "http-159.82.103.149-19332-Processor20" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28680]
  0x50968f28 JavaThread "http-159.82.103.149-19332-Processor19" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28679]
  0x50968178 JavaThread "http-159.82.103.149-19332-Processor18" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28678]
  0x509673c8 JavaThread "http-159.82.103.149-19332-Processor17" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28677]
  0x50a850d0 JavaThread "http-159.82.103.149-19332-Processor16" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28676]
  0x50a84320 JavaThread "http-159.82.103.149-19332-Processor15" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28675]
  0x50a835a8 JavaThread "http-159.82.103.149-19332-Processor14" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28674]
  0x50a827f8 JavaThread "http-159.82.103.149-19332-Processor13" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28673]
  0x50a81a78 JavaThread "http-159.82.103.149-19332-Processor12" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28672]
  0x5015a8a0 JavaThread "http-159.82.103.149-19332-Processor11" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28671]
  0x50159af0 JavaThread "http-159.82.103.149-19332-Processor10" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28670]
  0x50158d40 JavaThread "http-159.82.103.149-19332-Processor9" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28669]
  0x50157fc8 JavaThread "http-159.82.103.149-19332-Processor8" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28668]
  0x50bb9c40 JavaThread "http-159.82.103.149-19332-Processor7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28667]
  0x50bb8f20 JavaThread "http-159.82.103.149-19332-Processor6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28666]
  0x50926180 JavaThread "http-159.82.103.149-19332-Processor5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28665]
  0x4fefbc20 JavaThread "http-159.82.103.149-19332-Processor4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28664]
  0x501fdbb0 JavaThread "http-159.82.103.149-19332-Processor3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28663]
  0x50a58ba8 JavaThread "http-159.82.103.149-19332-Processor2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28662]
  0x50a17d98 JavaThread "http-159.82.103.149-19332-Processor1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28661]
  0x083ea958 JavaThread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28660]
  0x51c4a9b0 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28657]
  0x51c49590 JavaThread "CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=28656]
  0x51c485d0 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=28655]
  0x51c475d0 JavaThread "AdapterThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28654]
  0x51c46738 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28653]
  0x51c3cc98 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28652]
  0x51c3bf60 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28651]
  0x0805c0e8 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=28643]

Other Threads:
  0x51c393f0 VMThread [id=28650]
  0x51c4bf50 WatcherThread [id=28658]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 51328K, used 18119K [0xab4b0000, 0xaee90000, 0xb2670000)
  eden space 43520K, 26% used [0xab4b0000,0xabfe4470,0xadf30000)
  from space 7808K, 85% used [0xae6f0000,0xaed6d820,0xaee90000)
  to   space 7872K, 0% used [0xadf30000,0xadf30000,0xae6e0000)
 PSOldGen        total 466048K, used 0K [0x72670000, 0x8ed90000, 0xab4b0000)
  object space 466048K, 0% used [0x72670000,0x72670000,0x8ed90000)
 PSPermGen       total 262144K, used 14441K [0x52670000, 0x62670000, 0x72670000)
  object space 262144K, 5% used [0x52670000,0x5348a508,0x62670000)
```

Also i got one error reported in catalina.log. Please have a look into that too..

```
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:364)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:507)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:457)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:365

)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:394)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:320)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:411)
```

Comment: You could start by posting the error you got.

Comment: Crashes are in most cases unexpectedly isn't it?

Comment: Have a look in your `catalina.out` or whatever file your Tomcat launcher script outputs stdout/stderr to

Comment: Versions of jdk and tomcat are really old. Please check if you can update them.

Comment: First of all, thank you all for responding to my issue. Here is the detail that i can provide you.
I have found three logs.
1. application log , where no issue reported

Comment: 2. catalina log for tomcat. And issue described there:
  2014-xx-xx xx:xx:xx,174 INFO TP-Processor21 org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket - connection timeout reached
  java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:364)
  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:457)

Comment: But, i don't know if that is the reason describes why tomcat went down. 
 because when i bounce tomcat manually in DEV instance, i often found the same errors in log, but still tomcat goes up many times smoothly.

Comment: 3. err_pid file for JVM crash. And there is:
 # An unexpected error has been detected by HotSpot Virtual Machine:
 # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (1.5.0_03-b07 mixed mode)
 # Problematic frame:
 # C  [libc.so.6+0x276f6]  _setjmp+0x6

Comment: ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------
 Current thread (0x4feb6748):  JavaThread "TP-Processor21" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=28707]
 Stack: [0x4e06d000,0x4e0ee000),  sp=0x4e0ec1b4,  free space=508k
 Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
 C  [libc.so.6+0x276f6]  _setjmp+0x6
 C  [libfontmanager.so+0x45d4d]
 C  [libfontmanager.so+0x46349]  Java_sun_font_FileFont_getGlyphImage+0xcb
 j  sun.font.FileFont.getGlyphImage(JI)J+0
 j  ...StandardGlyphVector.initPositions()V+106
 j  ...StandardGlyphVector.getLogicalBounds()Ljava/awt/geom/Rectangle2D;+5

Comment: I have just posted some part of the err_pid file, but it seems like it is not well formatted here, so i think it will be difficult for you to study it. Please let me know if this information is helpful to debug the issue.  Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the absence of any tangible evidence, I can offer a couple of observations that might help.

1. You are using a really old version of Java.  Java 5 was released in 2004, and 1.5.0_03 is a very early patch release.  Public patches ceased in 2009.
2. Hard JVM crashes (that result in an "err_pid" dump file) are typically attributable to bugs in 1st / 3rd native code libraries, and occasionally to JVM bugs.
3. It is often possible to get clues as to what was happening by looking at the "err_pid" file.

---

My advice would be to upgrade your Java release, at least to the last publicly available Java 5 release, and ideally all the way to Java 7.  A Tomcat upgrade is probably warranted ... and also a general blitz on applying security patches to the machine.

If you have the wherewithal, you should try all of these remedies out on your test / UAT system before trying it in production.  Java upgrades and Tomcat upgrades have the potential to introduce problems, and you don't want experience them first in on a production server.

Secondly, if this is a once off event, the most productive thing you could do would be to save all of the evidence (log files, dump files, configurations, etc) and put the problem on one side.  Now YMMV, but in general it is only worth investigating this kind of problem if it recurs.  (For a start, with a once-off event, it is really difficult to know that you have identified the cause and implemented the correct remedy ...)

Comment: Hello Stephen, thanks a lot for replying. I have posted part of err_pid file which i think caught some error track, but i couldn't understand what is the error from that file. I request you to please have a look into it. And please let me know if it is not sufficient or you need anything else. thank you.

Comment: "Edited highlights" are not helpful ... you need to make the entire stacktrace + context and the entire err_dump file.  All I can say from what you have posted is that this *might* be something to do with the native socket code, and/or the native font handling.  Both are JVM code ... so a Java upgrade is recommended.

Comment: Hello Stephen, i couldn't post the entire err_pid file, coz posting is restricted to certain letter count. Please suggest what to do. Although i have posted part of the err_pid file starting from the beginning. Also what you are telling that it might be the issue with native socket code and i believe you suggest that after looking into catalina.log file of mine. But Stephen, i also get same kind of log when i manually reboot the server. Thanks a lot..

Comment: @user3378974 Stephen outlined it correctly: you should at least upgrade to the most recent java 5 version. This could be possibly an old jvm bug which might be fixed since years. If you're still experiencing this issue with the most recent jdk 5 available, update your question.

Comment: Thank you MRalwasser for your reply. But can you please tell me what are the possible issues i might encounter if i upgrade java version.I mean what are the probable challenges that i might have to face if i upgrade java version?

Comment: Assuming that we're talking about "upgrading to the most recent java  5 release": That depends on your applications, but in most cases, such an upgrade will work seamlessly with existing applications. But before going into production, you should test it to be sure.

Comment: Java upgrades are usually seamless for server and desktop applications ... even to Java 6 or 7.  There can be issues if you are using applets or webstart / JNLP, but these issues are all about tightening up security to protect the end user.  But of course, you should ALWAYs fully system test everything before attempt to deploy to your production platform.

Comment: Thank you MRalwasser and Stephen C. You guys are the leads to my problem. i will now look into updating the JVM to most recent java 5 version. But, i was also seeing around that SIGSEGV error might be related to Segmentation fault in memory. i know you guys definetly found the bug.. but can you please let me know where you found the bug in the log? this is i am asking just for my knowledge. Thanks a lot again